# shell script with variable length parameters

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments

How do I pass the entire argument list of shell script to a program?

So for instance, if I have a java program called JavaFoo that'd take any number of arguments, and this should be called inside my script.

How do I pass the script's arguments to the java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java /path/to/JavaFoo "$@"
```

to pass all parameters individually quoted as passed to the Bash script itself.
Works with Dash as well, but I don't know about other Bourne-compatible shells.

Say you want to pass all but the first parameter to the shell script on to the Java program, use `shift` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shift
java /path/to/JavaFoo "$@"
```

Use more instances of `shift` to get rid of more parameters before passing them on, if needed.

So say you call the shell script (`myscript`) as follows:

```
./myscript a b c
```

the `shift` will get rid of `a`. Add one more `shift` and it also gets rid of `b`. The name of the script itself is not included in `"$@"` even though you can access it as `$0` in many shells.

Comment: Yeah, adding the this works for me: `java JavaFoo "$@"`. Thanks

Comment: Oops, sorry. I was assuming the Java file had a hashbang :)

Comment: What would the `shift` do in this particular case? So say, if I called the script with the following command `./myscript a b c`, then script would get rid of the 0 argument (which is `myscript') and only pass 'a b c' to my java program?

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks